# Why are both elements on in my new water heater?

Tags: water-heater

Recently installed a new water heater. Both elements are on at the same time. Checked with the manufacturer to make sure this is not normal(it's not). Any idea what could cause this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you determining that this is the case?

Comment: This is a 50 gallon tank. I called Rheem and they verified it should start with the top element only.  The unit has LED Indicator Lights.

Comment: It has an LED light for each element?

Answer (score 4):

It is unusual for both elements to be on at the same time in a residential water heater. The upper thermostat starts heating the water and when it gets to the set temperature it switches power to the lower thermostat. The upper thermostat has a single pole double throw switch to the lower one so both elements can't be on at the same time. If it's happening, then the upper thermostat is either wired wrong or it's somehow defective.

If the water heater's wired correctly, #10 wire and a 30 amp breaker, two 4500W elements on at the same time would draw 37.5 amps +- and would trip the breaker.

Check again with the vendor and also check the nameplate info.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel   Thanks.... what's 8.99 million watts among friends..

Comment: I checked the wiring diagram and everything appears to be wired correctly. 5500 watt elements so probably closer to 45 amps?  So I have a 30 amp breaker in the utility room wired to another 30 amp in the main panel.  I powered up to see if one element would go out and after about 5 minutes the utility room breaker started buzzing a little.  I assume she was getting close to tripping so I shut everything down.   I was wondering if there was any physical way the thermostat could power up both elements at the same time so thanks for that clarification.

Comment: What does the nameplate on the water heater say?  The upper thermostat should not be able to power up both elements unless  there's some jumper installed or an internal short between contacts.

Comment: I'm sorry. What info were you looking for on the name plate?

Comment: @Mike  The wattage, the volts and the amps.

Comment: Yes sir. Phase: 1, Volts AC 240, Upper Element Watts 5500, Lower Element Watts 5500, Total Watts 5500.

Comment: @Mike  Yep, designed for one element at a time, thought they could have mislabeled the box. You said it was recently installed. Has it always acted up like this? Is it still under warranty?

Comment: It acted like this from the start. Under warranty however it's in a rural area so the manufactures doesn't have anyone in the area that can do the work. I can either do it  myself or hire someone local. They will cover the cost.  I'll let you all know how it goes. Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: @Mike  So you just turn it on for a bit hen you need hot water?  You can disconnect one of the elements so you won't trip the breaker...

Comment: I'll probably do that until I have a technician come. Thanks!

Comment: Service Tech came out on Tuesday. He found one of the wires leading to the lower element was pinched causing a cut in the insulation and short circuit.  The wire was repaired and rerouted.. The water heater is operating properly now and the breaker in the utility room is no longer buzzing.  Thanks to everyone for their help!.

Comment: @Mike  Glad you got  it fixed.  Stay safe up there.